# static function pointer in the abstract class

Tags: c++, abstract-class, function-pointers

I am implementing an abstract factory class.
In the base (abstract class), I define the following typedef:

```
// Logging callback type.
typedef void (*LoggingCallBackFuncP)(const std::string&);
```

and have

```
static LoggingCallBackFuncP m_LogCallback;
```

Also I want to have following function declaration the the abstract class:

```
static void SetLog(LoggingCallBackFuncP callback);
```

This function will initialize `m_LogCallback`
In such a way I want to get the opportunity to initialize a log function only once and use it for all derived classes.
Is this approach OK? When/how should I initialize `m_LogCallback`?

Comment: presumably you want the callback in order to get a bit more information about what objects the factory creates. then it is natural to assume that the factory is introduced just in order to get better control over which object are created. why do you need that?'

Comment: anyway, since the callback can be changed at any time, provide a do-nothing default. and do consider whether you want to support use of the factory from multiple threads. the best solution if possible is to get rid of the factory, and of any other java-inspired solutions.

Comment: in addition to considering threads you have to consider whether you want to support calls from static objects, i.e. calls before `main`. in that case the simplest code would run afoul of the static initialization order fiasco. it's not a problem when you make the callback function pointer a meyers' singleton, say, but then you have multiple code smells: factory and singleton.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this approach OK?

Yes.

> When/how should I initialize m_LogCallback?

Since `SetLog` is static, you can call it anytime, without the need for an object instance.

The syntax is `NameOfAbstractClass::SetLog( my_callback );`

Comment: The initialization of it should be done by calling SetLog.Where do I call SetLog?from which object?